# reledmac and reledpar: \msdata appears twice on the first page

Tags: luatex, reledmac, reledpar

I am editing a bilingual critical edition with reledmac, reledpar and LuaLaTeX. On the left page is the Greek text with critical apparatus and on the right page is the German translation.

It all looks fine but on the first left page msdata appears twice, not on the following left pages.

What I have done so far: I thought that it had to do with the fact that I have directly after `\msdata` many commands including for the critical apparatus, so I moved `\msdata` to another place temporarily. However, this didn’t work.

I hope someone can help me.

Here is my new MWE

```
\documentclass[headheight=8mm, paper=170mm:240mm, BCOR=20mm, open=any]{scrbook}

\usepackage[polutonikogreek, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{letterspace} % für Sperrungen
\usepackage{lipsum}

%% begin reledmac
\usepackage[%
series={A, B, C, D, E}, % A: Bezeugung, B: Wiedergabe, C: Querbezüge; 
% D: Verwendeter Text, E: Apparat
noend,                  % keine Endnotenapparate
noeledsec,              % keine eledsections et al.
noledgroup              % keine ledgroups           
]{reledmac}

\Xarrangement[]{paragraph}           % Apparateinträge in Paragraph, nicht jeder in eigener Zeile
\setmsdatalabel{}                    % Standardlabel für Bezeugung "Ms." löschen
\lineation{page}                     % auf jeder Seite Zeilen neu zählen
\linenummargin{outer}                % Zeilenzahlen außen
\Xnumberonlyfirstinline[][true]      % Zeilennummern nur einmal
\Xnumberonlyfirstintwolines[][true]
\Xtwolines[]{\,f.}                   % bei zwei Zeilen zweite durch "f." ersetzen
\Xtwolinesbutnotmore[]               % aber bei mehr als zwei Zeilen Begin und Ende nennen
\Xsymlinenum[]{$\parallel$}          % Symbol zwischen Lesarten aus einer Zeile
\Xnotenumfont[]{\bfseries}           % Zeilennummern fett
\Xnonbreakableafternumber[]          % kein Zeilenumbruch nach Zeilennummer
\Xlemmaseparator[A, B, C, D]{:}      % Zeichen nach Lemma
\Xnonumber[B, C, D]                  % nur Zeilennummern in Apparat E
\Xafterrule[]{4pt}                   % Anzahl Points nach den Apparatlinien
\rightnoteupfalse                    % sidenote beginnt rechts von Markierung

%% A: Bezeugung
\Xtxtbeforenotes[A]{\textls{Bezeugung}:}
\Xafternumber[A]{0pt}
\Xinplaceoflemmaseparator[A]{0pt}

%% B: Wiedergabe
\Xtxtbeforenotes[B]{\textls{Wiedergabe}:}
\Xafternumber[B]{0pt}
\Xinplaceoflemmaseparator[B]{0pt}
\newcommand\wiga[3][]{%
    \edtext{#2}{%
        \if$#1$#2\else\lemma{#1}\fi
        \Bfootnote{#3}
    }
}

%% end reledmac

\usepackage{reledpar} % für seitenweise parallele Darstellung von Griechisch und Deutsch
\firstlinenumR{10000000} % vermeidet Zeilennummerierung der rechten Seite

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}

\begin{Leftside}
\lineation{page}
\beginnumbering
\autopar

\pstart%
\msdata{L\,E\,S\,Lat.}%
    \textbf{\large{Titel}}
\pend
        
\pstart
\noindent
\edtext{%
    \lipsum
}
{%
    \lemma{%
        \textbf{§§\,1--5}
    }
    \Bfootnote{Text zu 1--5}
}
\pend

\pstart
%\wiga[\textbf{§§\,6\,f.}]{%
    \lipsum
%} % Wiedergabe
%{Text}
\pend
        
\endnumbering
\stopmsdata
\end{Leftside}
    
\begin{Rightside}
% Deutsche Übersetzung
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\lineation{page}
\beginnumbering
\autopar
        
\pstart
    \textbf{\large{Titel}}
\pend

\pstart
\ledsidenote{2:1--5}
    \lipsum
\pend

\pstart
\ledsidenote{2:6--9}
    \lipsum
\pend
        
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
    
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Thanks for the question and the example, but please shorten and simplify it until it is **minimal** (the "M" in "MWE"). In particular, your preamble contains too many specifications. Please cut them down to the minimum that still exhibits your issue.

Comment: off topic, but to get much better and more usable letterspacing, I recommend dumping the old package `soul` in favor of `\usepackage{letterspace}` and then use the command `\textls{}` (or just load `\usepackage{microtype}` which contains `letterspace`).

Comment: thanks for the hint with letterspace

Comment: Thanks for editing and sorry to bother you again. In order to compile your new example, I need to remove the custom commands `\vari`, `\quer`, `\wiga` and `\parcnt`, because they are not defined in your snippet. (In other words: the MWE isn't really "Working".) But if I go through with this, the issue disappears: there is *only one instance* of msdata ("LES Lat."). ...

Comment: ... That could mean that the source of the error is one of those commands. Could you try to eliminate them one at a time from your source, and once you've found the culprit, edit your example to include this one culprit? Only then we can test solutions

Comment: I have found the culprit/s. It seems to be a combination of \msdata and my command \wiga = \edtext{text}\Bfootnote{footnote}. It does not matter if I use my short command or the full command. If I comment them out, \msdata only appears once. If one of two of them is active, \msdata appears twice on the first left page. Maybe it has to do with my general settings of reledmac/reledpar. I will add a new MWE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will sound unhelpful, but... As far as your *example* is concerned, **the problem boils down to your use of `\lipsum` in conjunction with critical footnotes,** specifically inside `\edtext`. (And your custom command `\wiga` isn't directly responsible for it.)

Assuming that your *real document* contains actual text instead of `\lipsum`, this answer might be unsatisfactory, formalistic and useless.
But there's a chance that it might point you in the right direction – maybe there's something happening inside your *actual document's* `\edtext` that shouldn't - so I'm posting it anyway.

I've distilled your code down to a truly **minimal** example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

%%%             This custom definition has some issues, see below
\newcommand\wiga[3][]{%
    \edtext{#2}{%
        \if$#1$#2\else\lemma{#1}\fi
        \Bfootnote{#3}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\lineation{page}
\beginnumbering
\autopar

\pstart
\msdata{This text must appear only once!}%
Title
\pend
        
\pstart
\wiga[My lemma]{%
Some
%\lipsum            % try uncommenting this
text%
}{My footnote}
\lipsum         % try commenting this out
%
\edtext{Some 
%\lipsum            % try uncommenting this
text%
}{\lemma{My lemma}\Bfootnote{My footnote}}
\pend
        
\endnumbering
\stopmsdata
\end{Leftside}
    
\begin{Rightside}
\lineation{page}
\beginnumbering
\autopar
        
\pstart
Title
\pend

\pstart
\lipsum
\pend
        
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

Note that I have kept the calls of `\lipsum` **strictly outside** of the argument `\edtext` of the single footnote, and of the arguments of `\wiga`, which is but an alias for `\edtext...\Bfootnote`.
In this case, there is no issue with the repetition of the text in `\msdata`.

[image]

However, if you use `\lipsum` inside `\edtext` or the first mandatory argument of `\wiga` (which is the same thing!), the `\msdata` text is printed twice.

[image]

I do not know what it is that `\lipsum` does and the `\edtext` cannot digest – though if I had to guess, I'd say it inserts *implicit paragraph breaks* (one call of `\lipsum` prints seven paragraphs of "Lorem ipsum").
We know that `\edtext` is a "short" macro, i.e. *it forbids paragraph breaks* in its argument (and even throws an error if you leave an empty line).
On the other hand, it appears that any breaks created by `\lipsum` can just slide past `\edtext` – only they'll come back to bite you in the form of inconsistencies and repetitions.

Maybe you'll find something similar **in your document** that is the source of the repetition.

To isolate the culprit, *reduction (minimality)* is the way to go: strip down your code like I did with the MWE above, until you have a simple configuration that still produces the issue.

#### Improvements to custom command `\wiga`

1. Pay attention to the line breaks: By leaving too many line breaks unprotected, you'll get some spurious spaces in the document (in the main text as well as the apparatus). This is true of `\wiga` and of all `reledmac` footnotes at large:

```
\newcommand\wiga[3][]{%
    \edtext{#2}{%
        \if$#1$#2\else\lemma{#1}\fi
        \Bfootnote{#3}
    }     % this should be: }%
}

\edtext{%
    Some        % this should be: Some%
}
{%
    \lemma{%
        \textbf{§§\,1--5}       % this should be: }%
    }
    \Bfootnote{Text zu 1--5}    % this should be: }%
}
Text

% or even better: 
\edtext{Some}{%
    \lemma{\textbf{§§\,1--5}}%
    \Bfootnote{Text zu 1--5}}
Text
```

2. I'm not sure how the conditional `\if$#1$#2\else\lemma{#1}\fi` is meant to work (why the math mode?), but in practice, it doesn't. When #1 is empty, the command *prints #2 twice*.
   You seem to want a command that prints `\edtext{#2}{\lemma{#1}\Bfootnote{#3}`, where #1 is optional and, if undefined, defaults to #2.
   The canonical (and effective) way to do this, with any recent TeX distribution (>2020), is [the following](https://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf#page=5):

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\wiga}{O{#2} m m}%
{\edtext{#2}{\lemma{#1}\Bfootnote{#3}}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions and your answer! I tested your suggestions, and the problem seems to have to do with implicit paragraph breaks in `\lipsum` and spurious spaces. Probably, there is an implicit paragraph in my document as well (which I did not find so far).

Comment: @Cor Yes, I think it's worth looking for such a paragraph break. Maybe you are using `\\` or `\newline` inside a `\pstart`? Some `TeX` mechanisms might react funny to that. Or maybe you have a custom command that introduces a paragraph or line break? (Just guessing, but that's where I would start looking in my own document)